# change the UIButton image in UITableView UIButton click

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

In UITableView `cellForRowAtIndexPath` create one button with one image. write action for that button click to change the button images. here the code.

```
ButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"work_exe_old.png"];    
myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(250,10,34,34);
myButton.tag=22;
[myButton setBackgroundImage:ButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton addTarget:self  action:@selector(select_id:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

- (IBAction)select_id:(id)search
{
    UIButton *tempBtn =(UIButton *) search;
    [tempBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"work_exe.png"]    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

clicked the button images changed(**work_exe.png**). wen click the same button again means the image want to change (**work_exe_old.png**) its like check box in tableview. how can i achieve tis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing it in this way you can customise your code much better. Check the code below:

```
ButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"work_exe.png"];
ButtonImageSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"work_exe_old.png"];

myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

myButton.frame = CGRectMake(250,10,34,34);

myButton.tag=22;

[myButton setBackgroundImage:ButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[myButton setBackgroundImage:ButtonImageSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(select_id:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

And you can implement this selector method like this:

```
-(IBAction)select_id:(UIButton *) tempBtn {

  [tempBtn setSelected:! tempBtn.selected];
}
```

Comment: how can implement tis code in tableview cell image not displaying the cell... help me!!!

Comment: I didn't understand you what you said now. The above code you have to put inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method of `UITableView` if you are adding the UIButton dynamically. Be alert because cells are reused in the `UITableView`.

Comment: following this code first time (work_exe.png) images not displaying. if click the means(that black space) one blue colur high light images only display there..

Comment: Sorry. I have edited my answer. Check button instantiation line. Line number 3rd

Comment: You implement it. It will display now.

Comment: Tell me one thing, are you adding the button in your cell??????? Otherwise check your images. Remove the image reference and add it again.

Comment: want to create a button in tableview in button click change the button images

Comment: change ur code in 7 th line[myButton setBackgroundImage: ButtonImageSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected]; as per old code.

Comment: Oh! Thanks. I missed that while copying your line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want do a action by clicking on UITableViewCell you have to implement the **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** and before decalre `int i;`  gobally then follow the below code to make the changes for Button image

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

        switch (i) {
                case 0:
                   if(indexPath.row==0)
                     [tempBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"work_exe.png"]    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
                 else if (indexPath.row==1)
{
  [tempBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"work_exe.png"]    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
   else if (indexPath.row==2)
{
[tempBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"work_exe.png"]    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
.
.
.
 else if (indexPath.row==n)
{
[tempBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"work_exeN.png"]    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
                    i=1;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    if(indexPath.row==0)
                     [tempBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"work_exe0.png"]    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
                 else if (indexPath.row==1)
{
  [tempBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"work_exe1.png"]    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
   else if (indexPath.row==2)
{
[tempBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"work_exe2.png"]    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
.
.
.
else if (indexPath.row==n)
{
[tempBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"work_exeN.png"]    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
                    i=0;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

    [yourtablename reloadData];
```

note: write this code after the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

Comment: click the first cell the last cell button image was changing. wen the click the each cell that particular button want to change. the second time click the button high light image only displaying. (not showing the work_exe.png image)

Comment: may i know totally how many cells are in table.? @saravanaa . replay fast to make edit

Comment: total cells get from webservies.

Comment: its completed . check the edit and customise for urself

Answer (score 0):

set the uibutton's background images for each of its control states,

e.g.

```
UIImage *normal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"work_exe.png"];
UIImage *highlighted = [UIImage imageNamed:@"work_exe_old.png"];
UIImage *selected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"work_exe_old.png"];

[myButton setBackgroundImage:normal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setBackgroundImage:highlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[myButton setBackgroundImage:selected forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure weather I understand you right. If you want the image to change after a click, you should save the current state of your image somewhere, e.g. in an NSInteger that holds the state for your cell as a number that represents which image should be shown. In the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, put the right image (according to your NSInteger) into the cell.

```
@interface MyTabelViewClass() 
@property (assign) NSInteger currentImageState; 
...
@end
```

In the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, you somewhere have to decide which image to chose, according to this property:

```
switch (self.currentImageState) {  
  case 0:myCell.imageView = [[UIImageView imageViewWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"..."]]; break;   
  case 1:myCell.imageView = [[UIImageView imageViewWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"..."]]; break;
...
}
```

In the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath you have to change the state somewhere, like

```
self.currentImageState = (self.currentImageState + 1) % maximumNumberOfStates;
...
[self.myTableView reloadData]
...
```

Maybe it's a good idea to call reloadData with some delay because you want to wait for the deselection animation to finish first. You can do this by calling

```
[self.myTableView performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.35]
```

Comment: how can save the button state in array how to i implement ur method help me.any sample code